# Windows Anniversary Update (1607) crashes after install

Tags: windows-10-v1607

On a Dell Venue 8 Pro (5830, 32GB), I installed the Anniversary Update (1607) successfully. Whenever I boot into Windows, it completely freezes after about 10 to 30 seconds. Nothing is responsive. After looking at https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vufpo/windows_10_fully_freezes_after_anniversary_update/, I disabled AppXSvc in Safe Mode, which did fix the problem. However, this makes the tablet unusable since you cannot run any W10 apps.

Since the 1607 update worked fine on my other machines (2012 HP Pavilion, Dell XPS 18), I'm confused as to why this would happen. Besides rolling back or installing 1607 clean, what are my options?

Update:
I tried a clean install from USB and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that the specific issue with installing the 1607 update involved devices with a regular SSD and another storage option. In my case, I have the regular 32GB SSD with a microSD card, the latter of which has storage for my apps and documents.

Before installing the update via USB, I went to Settings -> System -> Storage. I then changed the "Save Locations" to make sure all documents and apps save to the original C drive (the 32GB SSD) and not my microSD card. The 1607 update went through and I no longer have the freezing issue.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a known issue with computers with radeon hd8500 drivers. The bugged driver is now fix so it would not happen again. Solution to get the computer to start: 
Start machine in securemode(power off machine 2 times, third time it should start in Troubleshoot menu.
Uninstall driver 
Restart maskin. 
Install new driver from your brand.

Comment: The Dell Venue 8 Pro doesn't have a Radeon video card.